# Understanding of the M1 transition $2s \to 1s$

Tags: atomic-physics, orbitals

I found a few articles [1] that mention the following dipole magnetic (M1) transition:

$$
2 ^{2}s_{1/2} \rightarrow 1 ^{2}s_{1/2}
$$
where a state is desribe by the notation $n ^{2S+1}L_J$ with $n$ the principal, $S$ the spin, and $J$ the total angular momentum quantum numbers.

How this transition can be possible ? With my understanding, the selection rules for M1 transitions do not allow this transition because the principal quantum number changes during the transition.

[1] Sucher, J. Magnetic dipole transitions in atomic and particle physics: ions and psions. United Kingdom: N. p., 1978. Web. doi:10.1088/0034-4885/41/11/002.